# Copy post link with Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'd like to process the link of a telegram message with telethon, but have no clue where to find this functionality.

When using Telegram Desktop, I can right click on a message and select "Copy post link" (took a screenshot from a random publicly availalbe group):

[image]

How can I retrieve the post link from a message with telethon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way of doing this in Telethon. In fact, there's no such functionality even in the full Telegram client API.

Fortunately, it's pretty easy to implement it yourself. Basically, there can be two types of links:

1. For public chat/channels.
   In which case the link looks like t.me/durov/10, where "durov" is the username of the chat/channel, and 10 is the ID of the message.
2. For private chats/channels.
   In which case the link looks like t.me/c/123456789/10, where 123456789 is the ID of the chat/channel, and 10 is the ID of the message.

All the needed info can be easily obtained from the Message object.

Comment: While taking a walk yesterday I thought about exactly this as the possible answer - so a big thank you for your response and the correct way of doing it!